# start .sh in .bash with a service or start the .sh file within the service

Tags: linux, bash, shell, service, gnu-screen

im currently setting up a minecraft server on my root but struggle with the startup on boot.

Before having this in startup i was starting the server with a .sh file which i had to start manually.
the .sh file also created a screen where i was able to check the console

.sh file:

```
screen -AmdS minecraft java -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M -jar /home/minecraft/server/server.jar nogui
```

But then i tried to have the server in startup of the root server so it starts automaticly

i created a service with a .bash file which starts the server with no problem on startup but without the screen option for the console

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Minecraft
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/start_minecraft_server.bash
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Standard Minecraft
cd /home/minecraft/server/
exec java -Xmx4096M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
```

now i want to ask if you know any easy option for adding the screen option to the service or bash file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and make sure your `screen` is actually in `/usr/bin/` by `which screen`

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Minecraft
After=network.target

    [Service]
    user=minecraft
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -S Minecraft_Server -d -m sh /root/start_minecraft_server.bash
    TimeoutStartSec=0
    
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But you should also alter your startcript itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Standard Minecraft
cd /home/minecraft/server/
while true; do
exec java -Xmx4096M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
done;
```

And just for security reasons, you should never run your mc server as root - create another user for it with limited permissions and add something like `user=minecraft` below the SERVICE tag in the init startscript